# Does this Keras Conv1D model correctly represent the intended architecture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm new to Keras and am trying to use a 1D convolutional neural network (CNN) for multi-class classification. I've created a simple model and want to check that it correctly represents my desired architecture.

My input data is a numpy array of shape `(number_of_samples, number of features)`, where `number_of_samples = 3541` and `number_of_features = 144`. There are 277 classes and I've used one-hot encoding to represent the targets as an array of shape `(number_of_samples,number_of_features)`. My desired architecture is shown in the picture below:

[image]

The code for my model (which I've run without any issues) is as follows:

```
# Variables:
############
num_features = 144
num_classes = 277
units = num_classes
input_dim = 1
num_filters = 1
kernel_size = 3

# Reshape training data and labels:
###################################
# inital training_data has shape (3541, 144)
training_data_reshaped = np.atleast_3d(training_data) # (has shape 3541, 144, 1)

# inital labels vector has shape (3541, 1)
new_labels_binary = to_categorical(labels) # One-hot encoding of class labels

# Build, compile and fit model:
###############################
model = Sequential()

# A 1D convolutional layer which applies 1 output filter with a window size (length) of 3 and 
# a (default) stride length of 1
model.add(Conv1D(filters = num_filters, 
                 kernel_size = kernel_size,
                 activation = 'relu',
                 input_shape=(num_features, input_dim))) 
model.add(Flatten())
# Output layer
model.add(Dense(units=units))

sgd = optimizers.SGD()
model.compile(optimizer = sgd, 
              loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')

model.fit(x = training_data_reshaped, 
          y = new_labels_binary, 
          batch_size = batch_size)

print(model.summary())
```

Does my code correctly represent my desired architecture? In particular:

1. My aim is that each of the 142 neurons in the output of the convolutional layer is connected to each of the 277 neurons in the model output layer, and that, on input sample `x`, the vector output by the output layer is compared to row `x` of `new_labels_binary`. From what I understand of the Keras docs, this model should do just that, but I'm checking because I'm new to this and the docs were sometimes ambiguous!
2. I don't mean this to be vague: is there anything in my model which is not (quite) correct given my desired architecture? I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure looks fine to me but if you want to solve a multi label classification task the output layer should normally have a softmax activation.

```
model.add(Dense(units=units,activation='softmax'))
```

If you dont specify the activation for a Dense layer a linear activation is applied.